# Read Frame-level features from youtube-8m tf-records

Tags: tensorflow

As denoted [here](https://research.google.com/youtube8m/download.html)  youtube-8m tf-records are saved with the format comes at the end of my question.I write a code to extract features. but there is a problem. the code can read all elements in features successfully but it is not able to read feature_lists. in fact, the example does not include features_list at all and I get an error while I try to access it.  How can I read the feauures_list. I attach Data format, My code and the output :

```
context: {
  feature: {
    key  : "video_id"
    value: {
      bytes_list: {
        value: [YouTube video id string]
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "labels"
      value: {
        int64_list: {
          value: [1, 522, 11, 172] # The meaning of the labels can be found here.
        }
      }
    }
}

feature_lists: {
  feature_list: {
    key  : "rgb"
    value: {
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [1024 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [1024 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
      ... # Repeated for every second of the video, up to 300
  }
  feature_list: {
    key  : "audio"
    value: {
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [128 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
      feature: {
        bytes_list: {
          value: [128 8bit quantized features]
        }
      }
    }
    ... # Repeated for every second of the video, up to 300
  }

}
```

here is the code :

```
def readTfRecordSamples(tfrecords_filename):

    record_iterator =tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=tfrecords_filename)

    for string_record in record_iterator:

        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.ParseFromString(string_record)
        prinr("Example :")
        pprint(example)

        img_string = (example.features)
        print ("Features are : \n")
        pprint(img_string)

        classID = (example.features.feature['labels']
                             .int64_list.value[0]
                             )
        videoID = (example.features.feature['video_id']
                             .bytes_list.value[0])
        print (classID,videoID)
        # Raise Error    
        rgbArray = (example.feature_lists.feature_list['rgb']
                         .bytes_list
                         .value[0]) 

        raw_input(LineSeperator)
```

and the output of the code is :

```
example
features {
  feature {
    key: "labels"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 66
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "video_id"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "-09K4OPZSSo"
      }
    }
  }
}

Features are : 

feature {
  key: "labels"
  value {
    int64_list {
      value: 66
    }
  }
}
feature {
  key: "video_id"
  value {
    bytes_list {
      value: "-09K4OPZSSo"
    }
  }
}

label for -09K4OPZSSo : 66
rgbArray = (example.feature_lists.feature_list['rgb']
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'feature_lists'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
example = tf.train.Example()
```

try

```
example = tf.train.SequenceExample()
```

and then verify with

```
print(example)
```

That at least works with Google's AudioSet dataset which reportedly has the same structure as youtube-8m (it also contains feature_lists), and needs to be read as a sequence example.